# Contextify install fails - "node: not found"

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

I cannot get Contextify to install on my system. I am running Ubuntu 14.04, node.js version 0.10.25, npm version 1.3.10, with node-gyp version 0.10.10

I've tried upgrading, restarting, installing dependencies first, everything. Nothing will get it to work.

```
~$ sudo npm install -g contextify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan

> contextify@0.1.8 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: 1: node: not found
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 127. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:431:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-29-generic
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had the same problem. Apparently Debian has renamed the command `node` to `nodejs` which is causing the problem. For me installing `nodejs-legacy` fixed the issue.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

See https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/issues/301 for details.

Comment: Or just symlinking node to nodejs

Comment: We just ran into this issue today and it had to do with the user running the install command using root. In your example above, you're running `**sudo** npm install -g contextify`. Try running it as the normal user `npm install -g contextify`.